# Modify Apache Tika parsing of ODF and old (1997-2003) MS Word docs?

Tags: java, parsing, ms-word, lucene, apache-tika

I'm developing an app which will do Lucene indexing of large files (splitting them up into multiple org.apache.lucene.document.Documents) of different formats. In the initial approach at least, each "Lucene Document" consists of one "paragraph".

As a general rule, Apache Tika appears to be a godsend for this: you simply throw a document at it and it appears to suck out all the text whatever the format.

But I wanted to get some detailed knowledge of how it handles trickier aspects, and in the course of my first look, at how it handles footnotes and endnotes, I find that whereas in a .docx file it will give this "line", for a line with 3 footnotes:

```
|Tecum optime[footnoteRef:2], deinde etiam[footnoteRef:3] cum mediocri amico[footnoteRef:4]. 
[2: Sed quoniam et advesperascit et mihi ad villam revertendum est, nunc quidem hactenus; 
Quod si ita sit, cur opera philosophiae sit danda nescio.] [3: Si quae forte-possumus. 
Immo videri fortasse.] [4: Huius ego nunc auctoritatem [sequens idem faciam]. Confecta 
res esset. Primum Theophrasti, Strato, physicum se voluit; Ut proverbia non nulla veriora 
sint quam vestra dogmata.]|
```

(NB the "|" characters are added by my code for clarity)

... with the same file in .doc format Tika gives you multiple "lines":

```
|Tecum optime|
|, deinde etiam|
| cum mediocri amico|
|.|
...

|??|
| ? Sed quoniam et advesperascit et mihi ad villam revertendum est, nunc quidem 
hactenus; Quod si ita sit, cur opera philosophiae sit danda nescio. |
|??|
| ? Si quae forte-possumus. Immo videri fortasse. |
|??|
| ? Huius ego nunc auctoritatem [sequens idem faciam]. Confecta res esset. Primum 
Theophrasti, Strato, physicum se voluit; Ut proverbia non nulla veriora sint quam 
vestra dogmata. |
```

... not only does it split up the original "paragraph" into several lines, breaking at each footnote ref, but it also pushes all the footnotes to the end of the processing.

With the .docx file handling you can extract the footnotes and easily link them to the sentence to which they belong.  The way the .doc handling works is of course pretty unhelpful for my indexing purposes.  Indeed I can't really see a way that the initial 4 "lines" churned out could be identified as really belonging to the same parapraph.

Perhaps it is to be expected that Tika's handling of an obsolete format like .doc is not all that wonderful. I am now intending to take a look at the actual source code involved here, assuming I can find it among the many, many source jars which Gradle has downloaded, but rather than tweaking the code is there a more "conventional" way of modifying Tika's parsing of a given format? I did some searching but found nothing.

Of course another approach might be to convert .doc files (and .odt files, see below) into .docx "on the fly" for higher quality parsing.

**PS parsing LibreOffice .odt files (Open Document Format, ODF), a non-obsolete format, is similarly problematic.**  In particular, the footnote/endnote-containing line gets similarly split up into multiple lines.

Comment: The .doc parser is https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordExtractor.java to save you digging through jars!

Comment: This looks like a great tip. But actually in my Tika API (1.14) org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor simply extends from Object. (http://tika.apache.org/1.14/api/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordExtractor.html) I'll take a look at the code for that class ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My findings a couple of days later for anyone interested.

First, it appears that the Apache people don't really intend you to fiddle around with the Tika classes.

When trying to tweak the handling of an MS Word 97-2003 format (aka .doc), the main class involved here is the `HWPFDocument` ("Horrible Word Processing Format"). Part of the Apache POI project, which comes bundled with Tika.

This class typically gets hold of an `InputStream` from a .doc File and seems to split the different elements of the file up rather unhelpfully, so that footnotes etc. seem to be stored separately from the text. `HWPFDocument` is `final`, which is only the beginning of the problem: many of the files here rely on other classes in the package or in sub-packages many of which are `final` or not `public` (or `protected`).  I came to the conclusion that I would basically have to clone the entire `org.apache.poi.hwpf` package, doctor it and package it up again.  I couldn't be bothered.

The **.odt (ODF) filetype** is really much more important to me ultimately: non-obsolete and non-Micro$oft. Here the crucial class turns out to be `org.apache.tika.parser.odf.OpenDocumentContentParser`. The problem here is that this contains a `private final` inner class (i.e. they *really* don't want you to subclass it or even use an instance of it for some reason!) called `OpenDocumentElementMappingContentHandler` which implements, ultimately, `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler`.  There are hundreds (well, lots) of `ContentHandler`-implementing classes involved here, many of them "decorators".  But ultimately what you need to do is copy the whole code of this class `OpenDocumentContentParser` and then mess around with the inner class. I made it so that at `startElement` and `endElement`, on the basis of the value of parameter `qName`,  it switches into or out of a "parse mode" of possible values "UNDEFINED" "NOTE_CITATION" or "NODE BODY" ... and on the basis of this mode setting can cancel the call

```
super.endElement(namespaceURI, localName, qName);
```

in `endElement`. It is this `super` call which appears to trigger the end of one string and the beginning of the next.  To put textual indications that a footnote number or body is beginning/ending in your output text you can create a `String injectedText` and then go

```
super.characters( injectedText.toCharArray(), 0, injectedText.length());
```

if and when appropriate. This is because the ultimate `ContentHandler` which actually ***does*** something is an instance of `ToTextContentHandler`, the `characters( ... )` method of which just adds a sequence of `chars` to a `java.io.Writer` instance (yes, I'd never heard of that either: very simple).

Hope this helps.  Have now submitted this new class of mine to the Tika project to see if they like the look of it.

Comment: Any chance you could raise a bug in the [Apache Tika JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA), and upload your changes to the ODF parser? We can then get those improvements into Tika!

Comment: Wow, honoured to be invited... will do so.  Have got it (.odt footnotes/endnotes) working quite nicely now: just like .docx processing, except I have found that for some reason the Tika .docx parser reports footnote "1" in a .docx as footnote "2", footnote "2" as "3", etc.: my .odt parser gets these numbers right.  Will raise both bugs...